# Spammers apply for an account, how to disable other users from applying for an account on my website

Tags: users, advertising

I am using drupal 7 and get messages like these several times a day:

Account details for sizemutter at "my Website Name" (pending admin approval)

sizemutter has applied for an account.

I am afraid that I may approve one of these by mistake. Is there a way to make it for them impossible to apply and to stop spamming me?

Thank you!

Comment: Try one of the spam protection modules on drupal.org? https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module?f%5B2%5D=im_vid_3%3A7266

Answer (score 3):

There are several options. In addition to disallowing vistor registration (Navigate to *Administration → Configuration → People → Account settings* and select "Administrators only" under "Who can register accounts?", you may you one of several contributed modules that is designed to prevent spammer and spambots from registration.

My personal favourite is [**Mother May I**](https://www.drupal.org/project/mothermayi).  It adds a field to the registration form where the registrant must type in a "secret word". If the registrant gets this wrong, no new account is created.  This is perfect for invitation only sites, where the invitation reveals the "secret word".  However, I find it works pretty well on other sites as well, where the "secret word" may be the answer to some a "riddle" that is solvable by humans but not by 'bots.

As an alternative to the above, there are are several contributed modules that let you add various types of CAPTCHA (Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart) challenges to forms, including the user registration form. These block spam robots, but do not block human spam registrations. However, blocking 'bots take care of about 99 % of spam registratons, so doing this helps a lot.  The most popular module providing a CAPTCHA is named [**CAPTCHA**](https://drupal.org/project/captcha). It comes with a built-in challenge, but is really a framework that to manage a set of CAPTCHA plugin modules, letting you experiment with these to find one CAPTCHA method that is effective for your site.

There are also contributed modules that provides a Drupal  interface to some external third party anti-spam service. The most effective of these is [**http:BL**](https://drupal.org/project/httpbl). an interface to the project Honeypot blacklist.  I've found that this module provides efficient blacklist lookups and blocks malicious visitors effectively.  (There a few false positives tho', in particular if your site attracts visitors that connects through TOR.)

Comment: for user self-enrolled sites, I have found that the combination of honeypot and reCaptcha works for me - I only see one every few months that manages to get by...

Answer (score 1):

Go to `admin/config/people/accounts` and select "Administrators only" under "Who can register accounts?"

Answer (score 1):

If your spam signups are from bots, do all the things other people have suggested (honeypot, captcha).

You might still have spammers manually getting past the Captcha, or maybe you don't like to use a Captcha because it drives away legitimate traffic. Your next step will be to block the IP addresses that the spammers use: Drupal's admin/config/people/ip-blocking blocks will report a 403 error to any connection made from one of the blacklisted IPs.

This can get tedious when spammers have a dynamic IP that keeps changing, or access to multiple internet connections. Use the [ip_ranges](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_ranges) module to block entire IP ranges that your spammers are coming from. It's much more powerful than the built-in IP block, which only blocks a single address at a time.

If you only expect traffic from a small geographical area, and your spammers are from other parts of the world, then there are GeoIP-based blocking modules that can also help.

At this point, the persistent spammers will start using Tor or other anonymous proxies to gain access to even more IP addresses, faster than you can block them. This is difficult to detect: What you need now is a service that tells you whether a remote IP is an anonymous proxy or a Tor exit node. That's where the [proxy_rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/proxy_rules) module comes in. Disclosure: I'm the author of this module.

The idea behind it goes like this:

- Set "Who can register accounts?" to "Visitors", allowing everyone who passed the earlier checks (IP blocks, Captcha, etc) to register an account without approval.
- Add a rule (you can do this in a hook_user_presave or with the rules module, which is great for this) to check the client IP when a new user is created, and block the new account if it matches a list of known anonymous proxies.
- Now administrators can review those signups and activate or delete them.

Or, if you don't want that hassle, just reject all connections from these proxies, the same way that the ip_rules module does it (I think it implements a hook_boot).

The module can identify Google Proxies by HTTP headers, and Tor nodes through a free DNS lookup service from the Tor project.

However, the list of anonymous HTTP proxies changes all the time. I do not know of any free data sources to implement, but the module supports external APIs and local databases (from udger.com and ip2location.com) that charge a monthly fee for their use.